# Typo3 Page Content Textfield missing

Tags: typo3

In my Content Element Block in the backend, I am encountering one problem my Text input field is missing. Is there a way, or a code block to get it back?

Ps. I am new to Typo3.

What I only see is this:

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

**Basics: At first a very general hint:**
Do you have installed any local extensions, perhaps even an own one? At start, as a beginner, you should remove those extensions, clear the cache and work only with the system extensions. Then you can enable the local extensions step by step and control always if everything is working.

**Basics: Records in the backend**
Even I've the impression you figured it already out, some very basics:

- In TYPO3 are different kinds of records in the backend, the very fundamental ones are the page records, which build usually in some kind the site-structure (depending on the menus).
- The content elements (like your text element) provide the content, and some special ones, like plugins, might need further records.
- The glue between all the records and the frontend is presented by the system templates, which have some more or less sophisticated TypoScript, either directly in the setup-field or included from a sitepackage. A combination of both is possible, the code in the setup field might overwrite included code then.

**Basics: TCA Definitions:**
Definitions how fields are rendered are included by table definitions inside TYPO3 (in contrast to mysql table definitions), called TCA.
Those table definitions are included by system-extensions and optionally further extensions.

These TCA-definitions can be overridden and manipulated on many levels, and this is what you're dealing with currently perhaps.
The hierarchy can be complicated but is usually like this:

```
1) TCA of system extensions with basic definitions
    2) TCA of further extensions, potentially overriding basic definitions
        3) Optional static TSconfig in the page-records by file inclusion
            4) Individual TSconfig code in the page-records
```

The point 3 of this list can still be separated by scripts that are included always, and those that can be included optional. The optional additions overwrite usually the other ones. You can see these options in this screenshot:

[image: fields of page record to include static templates and to enter individual code]

Ignore the names in my example, usually there is only one sitepackage, and you won't find my examples anywhere in public sources. Nevertheless, you should have something similar if you created a common sitepackage.

Ok, that's about the basics and now lets see what's
**About your question**

1. open the browser console and look if there is some error related to CKEditor. It might be that the field is just not displayed because there is a JavaScript error. If so, skip further steps but post the errors by editing your answer.
2. remove any definitions or file-inclusions in the page record to use just the default settings (refer to the screenshot above). Clear the cache and reload the page.

   Note that those definitions work from the root page in hierarchy down for all pages. Usually only the root page should include any files or scripts, even exceptions are possible and sometimes reasonable.
   So you might have to remove any entries from several pages in the page hierarchy.
3. Give feedback here, either if you succeeded or with further details like used extensions, type of sitepackage (i.e. bootstrap_package, or an own one), and further details that could possibly help us to help you.